# How to access the nonlocal variable in enclosing function from inner function if inner function already has its variable with the same name Python

Tags: python

I need to find the way to reference variable `x = "Nonlocal"` from `inner_function_nonlocal()`. Probably, the way how I referenced the `x = "Global"`: `globals()['x']`, but I need your help with that one, please!

Please note: I can NOT comment or delete `x = "Local"` in order to write `nonlocal x` instead of it.

```py
x = "Global"


def enclosing_funcion():
    x = "Nonlocal"

    def inner_function_global():
        x = "Local"
        print(globals()['x'])   # Call the global a

    def inner_function_nonlocal():
        x = "Local"        # <- This line can NOT be commented!!!
        print(_?_?_?_?_)   # <- What should I specify here in order to print x which is nonlocal?

    inner_function_global()
    inner_function_nonlocal()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    enclosing_funcion()
```

output should be:

```
Global (this is already achieved)
Nonlocal (need help to get this one)
```

Comment: Can you add another inner function, containing `nonlocal x`/`return x`, and call that?

Comment: No, I can't do that, Jason! Thanks a lot for prompt help, Thomas and Jason!
Anyway, we can close the question, unless there is any way how to reference `x = "Nonlocal"` in the similar fashion like `globals()['x']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method to get at the `Nonlocal` value:

```
x = "Global"

def enclosing_funcion():
    x = "Nonlocal"

    def non_local():
        return x

    def inner_function_global():
        x = "Local"
        print(globals()['x'])   # Call the global a

    def inner_function_nonlocal():
        x = "Local"        # <- This line can NOT be commented!!!
        print(non_local())   # <- What should I specify here in order to print x which is nonlocal?

    inner_function_global()
    inner_function_nonlocal()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    enclosing_funcion()
```

Result:

```
Global
Nonlocal
```